# Unexpected output table for permanova (adonis2 in r) to test for interaction

Tags: r, anova, manova

I am rusty with my stats knowledge, please correct me if I use the wrong terminology or misunderstand anything.

I am using adonis to perform a permanova test with the script:

```
nmds.div<- adonis2(nmds.dist ~ Season*Area, data = Type0, permutations = 999, method="bray")
```

Where Season has three levels (March, May, Sept) and Area has two levels (Pacific, Atlantic). The dependent variable is a distance matrix based on bray-curtis using OTU read counts.
I want to see the interaction term(?) between Season and Area but this is what I get:

```
         Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)    
Season    2   6.4903 0.27066 8.9066  0.001 ***
Residual 48  17.4889 0.72934                  
Total    50  23.9792 1.00000
```

When I run the same code format for Cruise and Layer3, the output table works fine and I get the interaction term - probability for Cruise:Layer3.
Where Cruise has three levels (KS17, KS14 and HO15) and Layer3 has two levels (euphotic, aphotic).

```
nmds.div<- adonis2(nmds.dist ~ Cruise*Layer3, data = Type0, permutations = 999, method="bray")
```

```
              Df   SumOfSqs         R2        F Pr(>F)
Cruise         2  6.4903090 0.27066356 9.787264  0.001
Layer3         1  0.4029121 0.01680253 1.215168  0.311
Cruise:Layer3  2  2.1654176 0.09030381 3.265409  0.002
Residual      45 14.9206109 0.62223010       NA     NA
Total         50 23.9792496 1.00000000       NA     NA
```

Table produced by:

```
table(Type0$Season, Type0$Area)
```

```
        Pacific Atlantic
  Mar        16        0
  May        27        0
  Sept        0        8
```

So, my question is how come the same code works for Cruise*Layer3, but not for Season *Area? Are there restrictions with the independent variables?

Comment: What is the content of your Area variable? Perhaps including some sample data in your question would make answering this easier.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I just added some descriptions for the independent and dependent variables.

Comment: To get a sense of the sample size of your data, could you describe the table produced by `table(Type0$Season, Type0$Area)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the short answer is that your model contains a high degree of multicolinearity because all of your "Sept" values came from the "Atlantic".

In other words, the additional factor of "Area" does not provide additional information, and so `adonis2()` drops a factor.

To see what I mean, here are two examples of simulated data. The first has the cell counts that match your data. Here you end up with a single factor in the result. 'Area' was dropped.

```
# fake data 1
nmds <- sample(1:1000, 51, replace = TRUE)
season <- factor(c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 27), rep(3, 8)), 
                 labels= c("Mar", "May", "Sept"))
area <- factor(c(rep(1,43), rep(2,8)), labels = c("Pacific", "Atlantic"))
Type0 <- data.frame(nmds = nmds, Season =season, Area=area)

# cell counts
> table(Type0$Season, Type0$Area)
      
       Pacific Atlantic
  Mar       16        0
  May       27        0
  Sept       0        8

nmds.div1 <- adonis2(nmds ~ Season*Area, data = Type0, 
                   permutations = 999, method="bray")
> nmds.div1

adonis2(formula = nmds ~ Season * Area, data = Type0, permutations = 999, method = "bray")
         Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)
Season    2   0.1720 0.02919 0.7216  0.583
Residual 48   5.7204 0.97081              
Total    50   5.8924 1.00000
```

In this second example, I provide random data in `Area`, which gives you greater-than-zero counts in all of the cells in the table. In this scenario the factors are no longer redundant. And `adonis2()` returns estimates for both factors and the interaction.

```
# fake data 2
nmds <- sample(1:1000, 51, replace = TRUE)
season <- factor(c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 27), rep(3, 8)), 
                 labels= c("Mar", "May", "Sept"))
set.seed(1)
area <- factor(sample(1:2, 51, replace = TRUE), labels = c("Pacific", "Atlantic"))
Type0 <- data.frame(nmds = nmds, Season =season, Area=area)

# cell counts
> table(Type0$Season, Type0$Area)

Pacific Atlantic
Mar       11        5
May       14       13
Sept       2        6


nmds.div2 <- adonis2(nmds ~ Season*Area, data = Type0, 
                   permutations = 999, method="bray")

> nmds.div2
adonis2(formula = nmds ~ Season * Area, data = Type0, permutations = 999, method = "bray")
Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)
Season       2   0.2721 0.04736 1.1661  0.313
Area         1   0.1721 0.02995 1.4747  0.233
Season:Area  2   0.0515 0.00895 0.2205  0.948
Residual    45   5.2510 0.91374              
Total       50   5.7467 1.00000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I think that is the case too... even when I try adonis2 without testing for the interaction term, by using the + operator instead of * it still drops certain factors. I guess I will have to select the factors I test carefully.